# str_replace %%~na File Name In Batch File

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, preg-replace

I want to replace the current file name inside a batch file

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do  ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -vf "drawtext=text=%%~na:fontfile='C\:\\Users\\harin\\Desktop\\test\\Fonts\\Glamy Sunrise.ttf':fontcolor=black:fontsize=54:x=20:y=50" -b:v 1M -r 60 -b:a 144k  -crf 17 "C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\in\Working\1\%%~na.mp4"
```

Need to replace `drawtext=text=%%~na` with some thing like this `drawtext=text=str_replace(array('-','_'),array(' ',''),%%~na)`

how can i do this... thx

Comment: Assign each `%%a` to a variable, delay variable expansion, and use variable expansion and replacement, `!var:-= !` and `!var:_=!`. There are thousands of examples existing within the pages of this site you can use to assist you in formaulating an solution armed with the abouve and using the search facility at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modification of the file name can be done using [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in (*.mp4) do (
    set "FullFileName=%%I"
    set "OnlyFileName=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "OnlyFileName=!OnlyFileName:_=!"
    set "OnlyFileName=!OnlyFileName:-= !"
    ffmpeg.exe -i "!FullFileName!" -vf "drawtext=text=!OnlyFileName!:fontfile='C\:\\Users\\harin\\Desktop\\test\\Fonts\\Glamy Sunrise.ttf':fontcolor=black:fontsize=54:x=20:y=50" -b:v 1M -r 60 -b:a 144k -crf 17 "C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\in\Working\1\!OnlyFileName!.mp4"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

It is assumed that the current directory on batch file execution is not the directory `C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\in\Working\1` as in this case a modification of the **FOR** command line should be done to process a list of file names loaded first into memory of `cmd.exe` before running the commands inside the body of **FOR**. This can be achieved by using as third line:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.mp4 /A-D-L /B 2^>nul') do (
```

The batch file code can be optimized to the following code if there is never an MP4 file in the current directory containing one or more exclamation marks in file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in (*.mp4) do (
    set "FileName=%%~nI"
    set "FileName=!FileName:_=!"
    set "FileName=!FileName:-= !"
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -vf "drawtext=text=!FileName!:fontfile='C\:\\Users\\harin\\Desktop\\test\\Fonts\\Glamy Sunrise.ttf':fontcolor=black:fontsize=54:x=20:y=50" -b:v 1M -r 60 -b:a 144k -crf 17 "C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\in\Working\1\!FileName!.mp4"
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

**Note:** It would be most efficient to specify `ffmpeg.exe` with its fully qualified file name enclosed in `"` if the full path contains a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` as in this case `cmd.exe` would not need to search for the file `ffmpeg.exe` on each *.mp4 file using the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT`.